# Second NSThread crash

Tags: iphone, nsthread

My app, when the user open it, starts an NSThread for download new data (parsing an xml file).
this is the code (in AppDelegate.m):

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
        NSThread* parse_thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(load_data)  object:nil];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
[parse_thread start];
[parse_thread release]; //is it right?

-(void)load_data{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
... //here the parser
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
[pool release];
[NSThread exit];
}
```

It works fine!

In the first view there is a tableview: the first cell need to read the GPS Coordinate of the user position and parse other data from a url.

this is the code (in myview.m):

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
loc = location;
[locationController.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
NSThread *parse_2 = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(load_data_2) object:nil];
[parse_2 start];
[parse_2 release];
}

-(void)load_data_2{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
//here the parse
[pool release];
[NSThread exit];
}
```

so... when the user touch that cell, the app crashes! And the console has no one log!
(if a call the method without use a NSThread

```
[self load_data_2];
```

it works without problem!

Do you know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `[NSThread exit]`, it's not necessary. Other than that, without the error information from the console there's not much to go on here.

Answer (score 0):

your messages to UIKit/AppKit objects should be made from the main thread. that's just the way it is, unless you have extended an object and explicitly added MT support in those sections.

Foundation defines a few convenience methods (e.g., `-[NSObject performSelectorInBackground*`, `-[NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread*`), so you can remove much of the boilerplate in your example, as well as the messages to UIKit objects from the main thread.

if the problem persists, you may want to post a more thorough example.

Comment: excuse me, i don't understand... what's the message to UIKit/AppKit object that i'm doing?

Comment: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;` <-- that's the one in the example you posted. there are also fundamental memory management and synchronization issues in your code.